# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'FILE_LENGHT_ERROR_MESSAGE')

Tags: visual-studio

I'm having a problem and no idea why the code is not working and returning a mock error.

H:\Thiago\programação estudo\modulo01\aula01-mocks\index.test.js:11

`const expected = new Error(error.FILE_LENGHT_ERROR_MESSAGE)`

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading
> 'FILE_LENGHT_ERROR_MESSAGE')
> at H:\Thiago\programação estudo\modulo01\aula01-mocks\index.test.js:11:40
> at Object. (H:\Thiago\programação estudo\modulo01\aula01-mocks\index.test.js:18:4)
> at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1356:14)
> at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1414:10)
> at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1197:32)
> at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1013:12)
> at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:128:12)
> at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49

Node.js v18.19.1

that's the error log and here my code:

```
const { error } = require("./src/constants")
const File = require("./src/file"); 

const assert = require('assert')

// IFEE
;(async() => {
    // variáveis criadas nesse bloco, só serão validadas durante sua execução
    {
      const filePath = './mocks/emptyFile-invalid.csv'
      const expected = new Error(error.FILE_LENGHT_ERROR_MESSAGE)
      const result = File.csvToJSON(filePath)
      await assert.rejects(result, expected)

    }


}) ()
```

a little help maybe.

I tried to read the error and realize that's a import problem but i can't find how to do the import right or what to change on code.

Comment: LENGTH is mis-spelled.

Comment: i fixed that but the same error persist.